# Create Bean Proxy on the fly for Injection in Spring

Tags: java, spring, proxy

I have the following situation: 
During the configuration/startup of Spring Boot, I am picking up a list of interfaces using reflections. These interfaces are replaced with a proxy implementation (using java.lang.reflect.Proxy, because I cannot use Spring's AOP). This is working.

There is a super and the actual interface. So I have something like this:

```
public interface Stream{
}

public interface ExampleStream extends Stream{
    doAction();
}
```

Now I want to use the interfaces in other beans unsing @Inject, e.g.

```
@Service
public class MyService{

    @Inject
    private ExampleStream exampleStream;

    public void fooBar(){
        exampleStream.doAction();
    }
}
```

And there is the method to initialize the proxy:

```
...
StreamInvocationHandler invoHandler = ... // this implements InvocationHandler (the proxy)
ClassLoader cl = ClassUtils.getDefaultClassLoader();
Class<? extends Stream> stream = ... // fetch the class, which is ExampleStream.class
Object impl = Proxy.newProxyInstance(cl, new Class[]{stream}, invoHandler);
ExampleStream exampleStream = (ExampleStream)impl;
// this is working
exampleStream.doAction();
```

The mechanism should be equal to the spring data repositories (except of the `@Repository` annotation and so on...)

But now, I don't know how to inject. Because of some SO answers, I tried to implement `ApplicationContextAware` as follows:

```
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
... // stuff from above
    AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory = applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    beanFactory.autowireBean(impl);
    beanFactory.initializeBean(impl, "exampleBean");
}
```

This did not work (field exampleStram in myservice has no qualifying bean...). I also tried another suggestion with a similar solution using `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor`, but this is only intended for bean definitions.

Where and how can I inject those kinds of self created beans?

Comment: I don't understand why you are doing this. A `Proxy` would typically be used to delegate to something. You're using it to actually implement the interface.

Comment: Since it's irrelevant for the question, I did not mention details and why I'm using the proxy. So I just wrote `doAction()`. 
But to clarify that: Similar like a JpaRepository, the `StreamInvocationHandler` parses the method signature and its annotations within the defining interface (here `ExampleStream`) and invokes approriate stuff. And I have to add: it's part of a framework where others will define concrete `Stream` interfaces

Comment: Look into `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` and `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`.